# Noob issues with NURBS-Python library

Tags: python

I want to use this [NURBS-Library](https://github.com/orbingol/NURBS-Python). In the given example the controls points are read from a *txt File, but I want to read them from a list:

`points = [(220, 340), (230, 350), (274.81862312, 374.16747697),
          (296.53778748, 432.99598526), (287.34352425, 482.4938853),
          (240.25166951, 533.10730113), (167.82511298, 566.76643201),
          (105.54327019, 576.83965142), (33.78721601, 565.2008206),
          (-4.53463006, 526.7978961), (-28.68208396, 467.04880685), (-30.68208396, 447.04880685)]`

```
curve = ns.Curve()
curve.ctrlpts(points)
```

This doesn't work: "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable"

Any ideas? According to the documentation it should work:

ctrlpts: *Control points of a Curve is stored as a list of (x, y) coordinates*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what line is the error on? And how do you get the ns object? :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see looking at the source code of the project you linked, `curve.ctrlpts` is a [property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work), thus

```
curve.ctrlpts = points
```

instead of

```
curve.ctrlpts(points)
```

should suffice.

Note: what happens with your current code is that you are indeed trying to use a tuple as a function (i.e. calling it). `curve.ctrlpts` calls the property getter, which returns the list of control points as a tuple. By writing

```
curve.ctrlpts(points)
```

you are trying to call the returned tuple as if it were a function, hence the error.